# Complex Analysis Question About Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, analyticity

I have some questions about knowing where and where not functions are analytic.
Here's a function,

f(z)= $\frac{Log(z+4)}{z^2+i}$

-I know that this function is not defined for z=$\pm$$\frac{(1-i)^2}{\sqrt2}$ being as though these are the solutions that make the denominator equal to 0. Why would it also not be analytic on the x-axis for x$\leq$-4?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, to maximise the set on which $f$ is analytic, chose the branch cut of $\log$ to travel through one of the zeros of the denominator.
$$f: \mathbb C \setminus (\{z_1\} \cup \{\lambda z_2 -4; \mathbb R \ni \lambda \geq 0\})$$
Where $z_{1,2}$ are the zeros of the denominator is the maximum possible area of analyticity.

---

However if you want to stick to the principal branch of the $\log$ it is defined on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, but you can cut any line from $0$ to any direction of $\infty$. Ideally you cut somewhere, where you already lost definition domain by the denominator, which is what I suggested. But if you want to use the principal $\log$,
$$\log: \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0] \to \mathbb C$$
Then $\log (\cdot + 4) : \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, -4] \to \mathbb C$
So this is why the analyticity goes away there.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all.

Comment: @Crypto The branch cut of the logarithm? Never heard of it?
The principal $\log$ is defined on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, but you can cut any line from $0$ to any direction of $\infty$. Ideally you cut somewhere, where you already lost definition domain by the denominator, which is what I suggested. But if you want to use the principal $\log$,
$$\log: \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0] \to \mathbb C$$
Then $\log (\cdot + 4) : \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, -4] \to \mathbb C$
So this is why the analyticity goes away there.

Comment: Sorry you got downvoted by OP. Your answer was just as valid and cooler than mine I would say. I upvoted you to compensate.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks, I added a section about using the principal branch as well to directly address the OP's "god-given" answer.

Comment: @AlexR, I specifically asked for why it is not analytic on x less than or equal -4 on the x-axis? I didn't ask for cool arguments, I'm an undergrad-I just needed a layman's definition. Just get to the point. I'll cancel my downvote to preserve your ego. Such diva's of mathematics are frowned upon.

Comment: @Crypto What I told you there is that you **DO NOT** lose the analyticity on a specific axis, but that the $\log$ forces you t sacrifice _one_ line from the origin to infinity. The principal ("default") $\log$ choses the negative reals as this so-called branch cut. But that's not necessarily the way to go if you want to reach a greater area of analyticity. My second section refers to the principal $\log$. So you can safely ignore the first if you don't want to. Still no need to get personal here.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly correct. The principal logarithm is usually defined to have a branch cut along the negative real axis, so $Log(z)$ is undefined for $z\in\mathbb{R}^-$.